# Heroku migrate causes: (staticfiles.E001) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to migrate the database from my computer to Heroku to run my app online.

using:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

returns:

```
?: (staticfiles.E001) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list.
    HINT: Perhaps you forgot a trailing comma?
```

My '#static asset configuration' in `settings.py` is as follows:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Based on searches, I've tried to turn this into a list with square brackets, adding a comma after the second `)`, and a few other attempts.

This is the second app I am creating from the same guide (Python crash course). The app from the book is working. The one I created for myself as additional practice is the one running into this issue but the coding displayed above is identical between the two.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I missed a step in the heroku django app configuration guide (I missed adding django-heroku>=0.3.1 to the `requirements.txt` ). 

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Heroku takes care of your static files with django_heroku package.  Install this in your requirements file, and add the import django_heroku to the top of your settings.py file and add django_heroku.settings(locals()) to the end.

To answer your question, if you must do this manually, you might try changing STATICFILES_DIRS to a list instead of a tuple, and make sure that the directory exists in the BASE_DIR that you are assigning.

You may need to add the STATIC_URL = '/static/' as well. This should be located in the same level as your manage.py file.